# How can I tell what type of computers are in a coffee shop?

Tags: pattern-recognition

This is more a thought experiment than anything.

I'm wondering what it would take to detect everything I legally can about the laptops in a hotspot. My first thought was to grab every MAC address I can and extract the maker from the first 24bit.

The question is would this be illegal and what else could I legally scavenge, preferably passively?

P.S. This constitutes a pattern-recognition problem so it IS programming... I think.

Comment: 'Question closed as "not programming related" by 17 of 26'. This, coming from the author of "How do you determine what your salary should be?"

Comment: @Ande, whoops - my brain fixed that one on the fly for me. Missed it.

Answer (score 3):

[nmap](http://nmap.org/) can do a reasonable job of guessing the operating system by the way the target system responds to various probes

Answer (score 2):

For the brain dead answer: *Quit typing and look around for a few minutes* :-D

Answer (score 1):

I guess the obvious one would be to sniff the user-agent out of their HTTP requests.

Comment: :) ...Anyone known the legality of looking at packet payloads on a public hot-spot?

Comment: Depends on the country, I guess. In the US you could probably get sent to Guantanamo just for looking at MAC addresses.

Comment: Instead of scanning the local network, you propose to run MIM attacks? =)

Comment: @Till That would only be needed for SSL, it nothing is encrypted you could get anything you want by sniffing packets.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there are ways to detect what TCP/IP stack is being used by sniffing choices in port usage and sequence numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter, 90% of them will be apples ;-)

Comment: But what version of OSX? What clients? what models?

Answer (score 0):

The people wearing black turtle necks will be using Macs, the rest will be using PC's and Windows (except for that one guy with long pony tail who is using Linux).

Comment: The only mac in sight right now came in with an owner in a leather jacket and an Iron Madden shirt.

Comment: Is Iron Madden related to John Madden?

Answer (score 0):

Packet sniffing is illegal without the network owners consent.  At least that's the generally followed precedent.  There has been very few tests of this in court.  But your idea of how to do it, using the mac addresses, would work well.  Wireshark is a good packet sniffer if you're looking.

Comment: IIRC and INAL, there is something about if you look at the payload that effects the legality. At least in some places.

Answer (score -1):

[GFI Languard](http://www.gfi.com/lannetscan/) gives a lot of info like this. Check it out.